# How to give the same rank to a list of ids by comparing them to another data file in LINUX?

Tags: linux, list, shell, awk, rank

I have list of ids (column 2) that I ranked from 1 to 600 based on their values(column 3). I have another list of the same ids but with different rank because their valuse are different. How can I comapre the rank/order of first secound list of ids from file2 with the first  list of ids from file1? for example:

```
file1:
     rank list-of-ids values
     1  HOUSAM69708729  0.4468
     2  HOCANM106363549 0.4434
     3  HOCANM10845509  0.4268
     4  HOCANM11098662 0.4203
     5  HOUSAM68571374 0.3896
     6  HOUSAM69990251 0.3895
     7  HONLDM716072164 0.3893
     8  HOUSAM69756113  0.3656
     9  HOCANM11098658  0.3593
    10  HOUSAM66626020 0.3538

file2:
list-of-ids values
HOCANM106363549  0.4832
HOUSAM69708729  0.4199
HOCANM10845509  0.4143
HOUSAM69990251  0.3887
HOCANM11098662  0.3792
HOUSAM69756113  0.365
HOUSAM68571374  0.3649
HONLDM716072164 0.3600
HOUSAM66626020  0.3593
HOCANM11098658  0.3545
```

the output file should be file2 with rank coming from file1:

```
output:
 rank list-of-ids values
 2 HOCANM106363549  0.4832
 1 HOUSAM69708729  0.4199
 3 HOCANM10845509  0.4143
 6 HOUSAM69990251  0.3887
 4 HOCANM11098662  0.3792
 8 HOUSAM69756113  0.365
 5 HOUSAM68571374  0.3649
 7 HONLDM716072164 0.3600
10 HOUSAM66626020  0.3593
 9 HOCANM11098658  0.3545
```

any suggestion, please? note that real data does not have any header and therefore, the out should not have header too.

Comment: What do you mean "that the real data does not have any header", can you please post what your actual data looks like in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$1; next }{ print a[$1],$1,$2 }' file1 file2
```

- `NR==FNR` - processing the 1st input file (i.e. `file1`)
- `a[$2]=$1` - capturing `rank` values (the 1st field `$1`) into array `a` indexed with corresponding `list-of-ids` values (the 2nd field `$2`)
- `next` - jump to the next record (`file1`)
- `print a[$1],$1,$2` - print fields (`$1, $2`) from the 2nd input file `file2` with corresponding `rank` value `a[$1]`

---

The output:

```
2 HOCANM106363549 0.4832
1 HOUSAM69708729 0.4199
3 HOCANM10845509 0.4143
6 HOUSAM69990251 0.3887
4 HOCANM11098662 0.3792
8 HOUSAM69756113 0.365
5 HOUSAM68571374 0.3649
7 HONLDM716072164 0.3600
10 HOUSAM66626020 0.3593
9 HOCANM11098658 0.3545
```

Comment: My real data does not have any column name. how can of remove "rank" as column name? my mean is that I should not have the first row(rank list-of-ids values) in the ouput

Comment: thanks. can you explain about your script? I want to understand it

Comment: @zara, sure, see my explanation

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, use ['join'](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/)

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 <(sort -k 2 file1) <(sort -k 1 file2)
2 HOCANM106363549 0.4832
3 HOCANM10845509 0.4143
9 HOCANM11098658 0.3545
4 HOCANM11098662 0.3792
7 HONLDM716072164 0.3600
10 HOUSAM66626020 0.3593
5 HOUSAM68571374 0.3649
1 HOUSAM69708729 0.4199
8 HOUSAM69756113 0.365                                                                         
6 HOUSAM69990251 0.3887                                                                        
ranks list-of-ids values
```

Admittedly, this doesn't handle the header very cleanly.  You've already accepted a solution, but I like this utility and not many people are aware of it ;)

---

Edit:  If the source data doesn't have any headers, then this command works great:

```
$ cat file1
     1  HOUSAM69708729  0.4468
     2  HOCANM106363549 0.4434                                                                 
     3  HOCANM10845509  0.4268                                                                 
     4  HOCANM11098662 0.4203                                                                  
     5  HOUSAM68571374 0.3896
     6  HOUSAM69990251 0.3895
     7  HONLDM716072164 0.3893
     8  HOUSAM69756113  0.3656
     9  HOCANM11098658  0.3593
    10  HOUSAM66626020 0.3538
$ cat file2
HOCANM106363549  0.4832
HOUSAM69708729  0.4199
HOCANM10845509  0.4143
HOUSAM69990251  0.3887
HOCANM11098662  0.3792
HOUSAM69756113  0.365
HOUSAM68571374  0.3649
HONLDM716072164 0.3600
HOUSAM66626020  0.3593
HOCANM11098658  0.3545
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 <(sort -k 2 file1) <(sort -k 1 file2)
2 HOCANM106363549 0.4832
3 HOCANM10845509 0.4143
9 HOCANM11098658 0.3545
4 HOCANM11098662 0.3792
7 HONLDM716072164 0.3600
10 HOUSAM66626020 0.3593
5 HOUSAM68571374 0.3649
1 HOUSAM69708729 0.4199
8 HOUSAM69756113 0.365
6 HOUSAM69990251 0.3887
```

If either of your files does contain headers, then you can just grep them out before the 'sort':

```
$ cat file1
ranks list-of-ids values
     1  HOUSAM69708729  0.4468
     2  HOCANM106363549 0.4434
     3  HOCANM10845509  0.4268
     4  HOCANM11098662 0.4203
     5  HOUSAM68571374 0.3896
     6  HOUSAM69990251 0.3895
     7  HONLDM716072164 0.3893
     8  HOUSAM69756113  0.3656
     9  HOCANM11098658  0.3593
    10  HOUSAM66626020 0.3538
$ cat file2
list-of-ids values
HOCANM106363549  0.4832
HOUSAM69708729  0.4199
HOCANM10845509  0.4143
HOUSAM69990251  0.3887
HOCANM11098662  0.3792
HOUSAM69756113  0.365
HOUSAM68571374  0.3649
HONLDM716072164 0.3600
HOUSAM66626020  0.3593
HOCANM11098658  0.3545
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 <(grep -v "list-of-ids" file1 | sort -k 2) <(grep -v "list-of-ids" file2 | sort -k 1)
2 HOCANM106363549 0.4832
3 HOCANM10845509 0.4143
9 HOCANM11098658 0.3545
4 HOCANM11098662 0.3792
7 HONLDM716072164 0.3600
10 HOUSAM66626020 0.3593
5 HOUSAM68571374 0.3649
1 HOUSAM69708729 0.4199
8 HOUSAM69756113 0.365
6 HOUSAM69990251 0.3887
```